# How to remove all rows in a numpy.ndarray that contain non-numeric values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I read in a dataset as a `numpy.ndarray` and some of the values are missing (either by just not being there, being `NaN`, or by being a string written "`NA`").

I want to clean out all rows containing any entry like this.  How do I do that with a numpy ndarray?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,np.nan], [7,8,9]])
array([[  1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  4.,   5.,  nan],
       [  7.,   8.,   9.]])

>>> a[~np.isnan(a).any(axis=1)]
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

and reassign this to `a`.

Explanation: `np.isnan(a)` returns a similar array with `True` where `NaN`, `False` elsewhere. `.any(axis=1)` reduces an `m*n` array to `n` with an logical `or` operation on the whole rows, `~` inverts `True/False` and `a[  ]` chooses just the rows from the original array, which have `True` within the brackets.

Comment: `np.isfinite` is also useful in this case, as well as when you want to get rid of `±Inf` values. It doesn't require the `~`, since it returns true only for finite reals.

Comment: @naught101 You also need to change `any` to `all`. Since you want to select rows where "all are finite", instead of selecting rows where "not any are nan".

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a masked array via `np.ma.fix_invalid` to create a mask and filter out "bad" values (such as NaN, inf).

```py
arr = np.array([
    [0, 1, np.inf],
    [2.2, 3.3, 4.],
    [np.nan, 5.5, 6],
    [7.8, -np.inf, 9.9],
    [10, 11, 12]
])

new_arr = arr[~np.ma.fix_invalid(arr).mask.any(axis=1)]

# array([[ 2.2,  3.3,  4. ],
#        [10. , 11. , 12. ]])
```

If the array contains strings such as `'NA'`, then `np.where` may be useful to "mask" these values and then filter them out.

```py
arr = np.array([
    [0, 1, 'N/A'],
    [2.2, 3.3, 4.],
    [np.nan, 5.5, 6],
    [7.8, 'NA', 9.9],
    [10, 11, 12]
], dtype=object)

tmp = np.where(np.isin(arr, ['NA', 'N/A']), np.nan, arr).astype(float)
new_arr = tmp[~np.isnan(tmp).any(axis=1)]

# array([[ 2.2,  3.3,  4. ],
#        [10. , 11. , 12. ]])
```