# Removing NAN's from numpy 2-D arrays

Tags: python, numpy, nan

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453141/how-to-remove-all-rows-in-a-numpy-ndarray-that-contain-non-numeric-values) I would like to remove some NAN's from a 2-D numpy array.  However, instead of removing an entire row that has NAN's I want to remove the corresponding element from each row of the array.  For example (using list format for simplicity)

```
x=[ [1,2,3,4],
    [2,4,nan,8],
    [3,6,9,0] ]
```

would become

```
x=[ [1,2,4],
    [2,4,8],
    [3,6,0] ]
```

I can imagine using a `numpy.where` to figure out where in each row the NAN's appear and then use some loops and logic statements to make a new array from the old array (skipping over the NAN's and the corresponding elements in the other rows) but that to me doesn't seem to be a very streamlined way to do things.  Any other ideas?

Comment: the long [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620914/how-do-i-remove-nan-values-from-a-numpy-array)

Answer (score 12):

You could use boolean indexing to select only those columns which do not contain `nan`:

```
>>> x[:, ~np.isnan(x).any(axis=0)]
array([[ 1.,  2.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  4.,  8.],
       [ 3.,  6.,  0.]])
```

(This is nearly identical to the answer you've linked to; only the axes have been switched.)