# Delete specific position from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have some numpy arrays with None in the first position.

```
a = [None, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b = [None, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
```

I want it to become:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
```

EDIT: I know I can do:

```
a = [a is not None]
```

But In my case I want to specifically remove a[0]

tried:

```
a = np.delete(a, 0)
```

got:

```
AttributeError: int' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all rows in a numpy.ndarray that contain non-numeric values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453141/how-to-remove-all-rows-in-a-numpy-ndarray-that-contain-non-numeric-values)

Comment: `arr[:, 1:]` will select all but the first column.  With `None` the array will be object dtype.  Without it it could be converted to numeric dtype, as with `arr[:, 1:].astype(int)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [efficient way of removing None's from numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254929/efficient-way-of-removing-nones-from-numpy-array)

Comment: It partly does, but this methods search the None's (O(n)). In my case, I know that it is in array[0].  There is not there a better way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove specific elements in a numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996140/how-to-remove-specific-elements-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: AttributeError: int' object has no attribute 'delete'

Comment: You have  messed up the `np` variable.  It no longer is the imported module.  Start over!

Comment: as @hpaulj mentioned, your `np` now is an integer, do `print(np)` to see. Standard numpy import should give you `module 'numpy'...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is a list:

```
In [61]: a = [None, 1,2,3,4]
In [62]: a
Out[62]: [None, 1, 2, 3, 4]
In [63]: a[1:]               # standard list slicing
Out[63]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If we have an array, we can do the same slicing:

```
In [64]: A = np.array(a)
In [65]: A
Out[65]: array([None, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=object)
In [66]: A[1:]
Out[66]: array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=object)
In [67]: A[1:].astype(int)
Out[67]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

With `None` the array is object dtype, similar to a list.

With the list, we can also us `del` (and remove any selected item):

```
In [68]: a
Out[68]: [None, 1, 2, 3, 4]
In [69]: del a[0]
In [70]: a
Out[70]: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`np.delete` does something similar for an array, though it isn't as efficient:

```
In [72]: np.delete(A, 0)
Out[72]: array([1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=object)
```

If `np.delete` doesn't work for you, it's because you've messed up `np`.

Comment: Slicing solved it! As for np.delete, it  worked when I tested it on some random array, but for some reason it is not working in my program's array.. anyway ty!

Answer (score 0):

Numpy just have a beautiful method. Use `.delete()`

Example:

```
n = [None, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = np.delete(n, 0)
```

**EDIT** : np stands for numpy. Use: `import numpy as np`

Comment: AttributeError: "Int" object has no attribute 'delete'